# FireFoxのlast_visit_dateの見方について

Tags: sqlite, firefox

お世話になります。
以下はFirefoxのplaces.sqliteの中身です。そして、last_visit_dateを降順にしたものです。

[image: Firefoxのplaces.sqlite]

last_visit_dateをクリックして降順にしても、かなり前の履歴が表示されています。
（つまり、先程まで見ていたサイトがここを押しても表示されません）

この仕組は、どういうことなのでしょうか？【一度質問を投稿してから追加した文です→】UNIX時間で表示されているとしても、たとえば４行目、５行目は桁が明らかに違うのにこのように表示されてしまうのは何故でしょうか？
また、【さっきまでブラウザで見ていた順】から順繰りに表示するには、どうすれば良いですか？

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 想定できる状況としては、過去のある時点でプライベートブラウジングの設定を行った、という場合です。実際、プライベートブラウジングの状態では `places.sqlite` に履歴が残りません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下は参考情報としてお読み下さい。

こちらの環境は以下の通りになります。

```c
$ lsb_release -ir
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Release:    21.04

$ firefox --version
Mozilla Firefox 91.0.2
```

コマンドラインから `places.sqlite` の内容を確認してみます。

※ `moz_places.last_visit_date` は μ秒単位の整数値で格納されています

```c
$ sqlite3 places.sqlite
SQLite version 3.34.1 2021-01-20 14:10:07
Enter ".help" for usage hints.

sqlite> .mode markdown
sqlite> select title,
        datetime(last_visit_date/1000000, 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as last_visit
        from moz_places order by last_visit_date desc limit 10;
```

| title | last_visit |
| --- | --- |
| sqlite - FireFoxのlast_visit_dateの見方について - スタック・オーバーフロー | 2021-09-04 21:59:16 |
| スタック・オーバーフロー | 2021-09-04 21:59:10 |
| Firefox がハングアップまたは応答なしになる | Firefox ヘルプ | 2021-09-04 21:51:46 |
| firefox 最新版 不具合 - Google 検索 | 2021-09-04 21:51:40 |
| firefox - Google 検索 | 2021-09-04 21:48:01 |

> たとえば４行目、５行目は桁が明らかに違うのにこのように表示されてしまうのは何故でしょうか？

桁数は同じです。表示用のフォントがプロポーショナルフォントであるために `9` の文字幅が他の数字よりも若干広く、結果的にずれが生じています。